# Chrome extension: Javascript injection to active tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a context menu entry to launch a new page on a new tab based on selected text, and then a javascript code to modify the DOM elements of the new tab. My `manifest.json` file is:

```
 {
    "name": "ContextBox",
    "description": "An experimental context menu addition",
    "version": "0.5",

    "permissions": [
                "contextMenus"
                ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
     },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

And my code from background.js:

```
    .
    .
    //this is part of handler for context menu item event onClick
    window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
    setTimeout(prxAsync, 1000);
}


function prxAsync(){
     chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"alert('hello');"} );
    });
    return;
}
```

This just doesn't work. The executeScript doesn't work but doesn't shows any error either (using try-catch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mixing in `window.open`, you can stay within the bounds of Chrome API.

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: 'https://www.google.com'}, function(tab){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:"alert('hello');"} );
});
```

No timeout, no roundabout tab search.

That said, **you need host permissions for [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi)**. `"activeTab"` will not help you here, as you're creating a new tab.

```
"permissions": [
  "contextMenus", "https://www.google.com/*"
],
```

You can use blanket permissions like `"<all_urls>"`, but if you have a preset number of pages you want to open it's better to list them explicitly.

Comment: Note, it's possible that `executeScript` call also requires `"tabs"` permission, but it's not certain.

Comment: Thank you. It totally worked.. I had permission problem, btw.